# Simulating in Altium Designer

Tags: simulation, altium, spice

I have very little experience with Spice simulations, and I have never simulated in Altium Designer. Whenever I install a simulation model there is an option to choose LTSPICE, PSPICE, or MixedSim.

1. What criteria can I use to choose the file format type?
2. Let's say I have a Pspice file for one component and an LTspice file for another. Is that a problem?

[image: SIM MODEL]

Comment: Try using PSpice, because the models that are made for it are, in general, SPICE compatibe. If it doesn't work, try LTspice, that's PSpice compatible for most cases. No idea what "MixedSim" means or does, but since they're options, just try them all out and see which one works. I don't have Altium, so this is just an idea.